# how to Filter main rep

Tags: sql

I need to filter out any rows in the following, where the 
order# appears with more than one rep we want the earlist in date time
so that

```
order#  Ordrep orddate   ordtime   ordsalescodes
123     222    20150501  080000    CHT
123     333    20150501  060000    WEB
123     333    20150505  110000    sls
```

here we want rep 333 row not any other reps but we do want all the 333 rows.

```
Select Ord.Num
       ,Ord.date
       ,Ord.Time
       ,Ord.Amt
       ,Ord.Rep
       ,Ord.SalesCode
FROM OrdersTable
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Either you want "the earliest in datetime" or "all the 333 rows".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select a row if there are no older row with same order#:

```
select Ord.Num
       ,Ord."date"
       ,Ord."Time"
       ,Ord.Amt
       ,Ord.Rep
       ,Ord.SalesCode
FROM OrdersTable Ord
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from OrdersTable ord2
                  where Ord.Num = ord2.Num
                    and (Ord2."date" < Ord."date"
                         or (Ord2."date" = Ord."date"
                             and Ord2."time" < Ord."time")))
```

Note that date and time are reserved words in standard SQL, that's why they are "delimited" above.

Also, why separate columns for date and time? I'd have one column for timestamp instead.

Comment: ok that the date and time are separate like that in the database erp.